# MySQL full text search and apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just learning about full text search in MySQL and trying to implement it into a website thats currently using the MYSQL LIKE command.

It works really well except when someone types something like `McDonald's`

The apostrophe causes:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
AND
        MATCH(client.clientName, client.clientDesc, offer.offerSaving, offer.offerDesc) AGAINST(+'$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)    
        GROUP BY offer.idoffer ORDER BY distance ASC, offer.offerScore DESC
```

The `McDonald's` is saved in the database as `McDonald's` however it would be good if it could come back with with `McDonald's` if they type it with the apostrophe or without.  Is this possible too?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-escape-string.html

Comment: Can you mark this up as a proper answer please it works perfectly?

Comment: The error is in whatever language you use to write your application. You're composing SQL by concatenating strings, while you should be passing values separately (prepared statements).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)